# Parse a column with X unique values into X new columns, populated with values from another column R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I want to take a column (A) with X unique values, and create X new columns, then populate each of those new columns with values from another column (B).  I have struggled to articulate this question in searches and haven't found anything yet so here are some example data to illustrate what I'm actually trying to do.

I have a data frame of agricultural yield (response variable) from several treatments over a few years.  I also have a data frame of agricultural inputs (predictors) during different months of the year (months 1, 2, 3).  Eventually, I'd like to be able to run models like `Yield ~ Input_mo1 * Input_mo2` so I'm trying to create separate columns that show the inputs for each month (i.e. `Input_mo1` are the inputs during month 1 of the year).

Here are my two input data frames:

```
yield.vector <- c(95, 6, 40, 34, 61, 16, 29, 69, 77, 54, 29, 94, 16, 61, 49, 18, 51, 87)
input.vector <- c(9, 6, 7, 3, 6, 2, 2, 9, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1)
data.yield <- data.frame(Year = c(rep(2020,6), rep(2019,6), rep(2018,6)),
                         Treatment = c(rep(1:2,9)),
                         Yield = yield.vector)
data.inputs <- data.frame(Year = c(rep(2020,6), rep(2019,6), rep(2018,6)),
                            Treatment = c(rep(1:2,9)),
                            Month = rep(1:3,6),
                            Input = input.vector)
```

I would like to create this kind of merged data frame where there is both yield and a column for each month's inputs:

```
data.output <- data.frame(Year = c(rep(2020,6), rep(2019,6), rep(2018,6)),
                         Treatment = c(rep(1:2,9)),
                         Yield = yield.vector,
                         Input_mo1 = c(9,3,9,3,9,3,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,4,1,4,1,4),
                         Input_mo2 = c(6,6,6,6,6,6,5,9,5,9,5,9,5,2,5,2,5,2),
                         Input_mo3 = c(1,4,1,4,1,4,5,2,5,2,5,2,6,1,6,1,6,1))
data.output
```

You'll notice that in the output data frame, much of the data is repeated since there are three replicates of each treatment in each year and they all received the same inputs within a given month_year.  The names of the output columns don't matter, as long as I can differentiate them and rename them later.

I've spent hours trying to figure out how to do this but I keep hitting dead ends.  I'll appreciate any help you can give.  Thank you.

Comment: your desired output is not correct.  For example, Year = 2000, Yield = 95, input_mo3 should be 7 not 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse` you can try the following. You can put your 3 months of data in separate columns with `pivot_wider`. Then, you can join your two data frames together. The data does not match your `data.output` data.frame exactly - please let me know if I'm missing something.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.inputs %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Year, Treatment), 
              names_from = Month, 
              values_from = Input, 
              names_prefix = "Input_mo") %>%
  right_join(data.yield)
```

**Output**

```
    Year Treatment Input_mo1 Input_mo2 Input_mo3 Yield
   <dbl>     <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1  2020         1         9         6         7    95
 2  2020         1         9         6         7    40
 3  2020         1         9         6         7    61
 4  2020         2         3         6         2     6
 5  2020         2         3         6         2    34
 6  2020         2         3         6         2    16
 7  2019         1         2         5         2    29
 8  2019         1         2         5         2    77
 9  2019         1         2         5         2    29
10  2019         2         1         9         2    69
11  2019         2         1         9         2    54
12  2019         2         1         9         2    94
13  2018         1         1         5         6    16
14  2018         1         1         5         6    49
15  2018         1         1         5         6    51
16  2018         2         4         2         1    61
17  2018         2         4         2         1    18
18  2018         2         4         2         1    87
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for and it worked out well.